# WPF: ListViewIndex from PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event using command

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

I want to get index of `ListViewIndex` from `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event using command:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewFiles">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListViewItemMouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewFiles, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Code:

Here i have my `ListView` and i cannot find a way to get my `ListViewItem` index or object.
I try `SelectedItem` but its `null`

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var listView = parameter as ListView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` is triggered *before* the item is selected so this approach of using an `EventTrigger` won't work.

You could hook up an event handler to the `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` using the `AddHandler` method and the `handledEventsToo` parameter in the code-behind of the view:

```
ListViewFiles.AddHandler(ListView.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((ss, ee) => 
{
    (DataContext as YourViewModel).ListViewItemMouseLeftButtonDownCommand.Execute(ListViewFiles.SelectedItem);
}), true);
```

This is not any worse than using an `EventTrigger` in the XAML markup as far as MVVM is concerned, but if you want to be able to share this functionality across several views, you may create an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF):

```
public static class MouseLeftButtonDownBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(ListView listView) =>
        (ICommand)listView.GetValue(CommandProperty);

    public static void SetCommand(ListView listView, ICommand value) =>
        listView.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(MouseLeftButtonDownBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandChanged));

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView)d;

        ICommand oldCommand = e.OldValue as ICommand;
        if (oldCommand != null)
            listView.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, (MouseButtonEventHandler)OnMouseLeftButtonDown);

        ICommand newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand;
        if (newCommand != null)
            listView.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, (MouseButtonEventHandler)OnMouseLeftButtonDown, true);
    }

    private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
        ICommand command = GetCommand(listView);
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(listView.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView Name="ListViewFiles" 
    local:MouseLeftButtonDownBehavior.Command="{Binding ListViewItemMouseLeftButtonDownCommand}" />
```

Comment: What is Window43?

Comment: It should be replaced by "YourViewModel" or whatever the name of the class where the command is defined is.